# org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Driver can process one query at one time at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.sendQuery(QueryExecutor.java:444)

Tags: java, netezza, dataflow

I am running a simple select query in Netezza Database and getting following error. What could the reason be?

> org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Driver can process one query at one time  at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.sendQuery(QueryExecutor.java:444)

Comment: 2018-07-31 (23:15:11) org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Driver can process one query at one time 
org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: Driver can process one query at one time 
at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.sendQuery(QueryExecutor.java:444) 
at org.netezza.internal.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:73) 
at org.netezza.sql.NzConnection.execute(NzConnection.java:2908) 
at org.netezza.sql.NzStatement._execute(NzStatement.java:891) 
at org.netezza.sql.NzPreparedStatament.executeQuery(NzPreparedStatament.java:212) 
at at

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show the query that causes this error. Please also edit your question to show the full error instead of putting it in a comment. Note: I have **no experience** with your technology stack at all, but it appears you have more than one query happening. Showing the `select` query will allow other people (not me) to answer your question.